# How is an adjunction map of a probability space well-defined?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, functions

### The book says something like:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.
Let $\Delta \notin \mathcal{F}$, suppose that for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $F \supset \Delta$, we have $P(F) = 1$.  $\Delta$ is then called *thick* in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.   Now define $(\Delta, \Delta \cap \mathcal{F}, P^*)$ by $P^*(\Delta \cap F) = P(F)$.  Firstly, $P^*$ is well defined.

### Attempt:

Let $F \neq F'$ be in $\mathcal{F}$, and suppose $\Delta \cap F = \Delta \cap F'$.  $P^*(\Delta \cap F) = P(F) = \dots ?$